# Why can't dot notation be used on id, when regular syntax can?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *something;

@end
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@implementation MyClass

@end
```

Then I do this:

```
    MyClass *instance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    id theSame = instance;

    [theSame setSomething:@"hh"];   // No error
    theSame.something = @"hh";    // "Property 'something' not found…"
```

Why does the fourth line give an error, but not the third? They are doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: because id doesn't have any properties

Comment: Check this:- http://qualitycoding.org/dot-notation/

Comment: Just because the semantics of parsing Objective-C is defined like so. The compiler permits sending arbitrary messages to `id`, but properties must be declared. (that, amongst others, is the reason they  are called "declared" properties.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some debate around it and especially programmers that were around before declared properties will advise against using the dot synthax. However, like any other language, Obective-C evolved and I think it did in the right direction. Now, to answer your question, you can think of the dot synthax as a way to access a property. id has no declared properties so, trying to access one will lead to a compile time error. On the other hand, when you use the method synthax, think of it as sending a message to a receiver, which is evaluated at runtime. So, sending any message to id is ok at compile time, the compiler assumes you know what you're doing and that the receiver will handle the message somehow at runtime. So, you can take great advantage of this difference: use the dot notation all the time, but use the method synthax when you know for sure the receiver can handle the message, but the compiler doesn't know. (this situations are somehow rare, but very important, they allow you to harness Objective-C's dynamism)